# Window is leaking into stucco

Tags: windows, leak, stucco, leaking, window-frame

I have some water that has worked its way into the baseboard of my house. The leak is directly below the corner of a window. It looks like the previous owner had the stucco repaired but a gap has developed (or was there from a poor repair job).

Is a repair here just a matter of filling in the gap with some caulking?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would caulk all around the window opening, sealing the stucco to the window.  Don't caulk the black window weep hole.

Generally if the house had proper rainscreen behind the stucco it wouldn't matter.  Stucco is a water sink so it will absorb water.  Any water that gets behind the stucco should have a drainage plane to get out.  Generally you'd osb/plywood your framing, then you apply building paper/tyvek/typar/etc, then you apply 1/2" or thicker vertical strips or a stucco drainage mat. You then chicken wire or stucco on top, leaving an air gap behind for drying potential.  Older construction didn't use a rainscreen and instead relied on the wall cavities being empty and drafty to allow drying potential.

Is there a metal window header flashing with side dams on the exterior above the top window trim?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

There is nothing sticking out past the stucco above the window so I don't believe there is any flashing.

I don't know how to check for the drainage plane. I assume I have one but then I am not sure how the water is flowing towards the house. Maybe it puddles and wicks in during heavy rain?

The water wet the base board but did not wet the carpet so I don't think much made it in. Though there is some mold so I assume it has been happening for a while. 

I am drying the inside now with a fan. Any specific caulking I should use on the outside?